# Building a list of months by iterating between two dates in a list (Python)

Tags: python

I have an ordered (i.e. sorted) list that contains dates sorted (as datetime objects) in ascending order.

I want to write a function that iterates through this list and generates another list of the first available dates for each month.

For example, suppose my sorted list contains the following data:

```
A = [
'2001/01/01',
'2001/01/03',
'2001/01/05',
'2001/02/04',
'2001/02/05',
'2001/03/01',
'2001/03/02',
'2001/04/10',
'2001/04/11',
'2001/04/15',
'2001/05/07',
'2001/05/12',
'2001/07/01',
'2001/07/10',
'2002/03/01',
'2002/04/01',
]
```

The returned list would be

```
B = [
'2001/01/01',
'2001/02/04',
'2001/03/01',
'2001/04/10',
'2001/05/07',
'2001/07/01',
'2002/03/01',
'2002/04/01',
]
```

The logic I propose would be something like this:

```
def extract_month_first_dates(input_list, start_date, end_date):
    #note: start_date and end_date DEFINITELY exist in the passed in list
    prev_dates, output = [],[]  # <- is this even legal?
    for (curr_date in input_list):
        if ((curr_date < start_date) or (curr_date > end_date)):
            continue

        curr_month = curr_date.date.month
        curr_year = curr_date.date.year
        date_key = "{0}-{1}".format(curr_year, curr_month)
        if (date_key in prev_dates):
            continue
        else:
            output.append(curr_date)
            prev_dates.append(date_key)

    return output
```

Any comments, suggestions? - can this be improved to be more 'Pythonic' ?

Comment: @"# <- is this even legal?": yes, it's called *multiple assignment*

Comment: `for (curr_date in input_list)` is a syntax error; no parentheses here in Python.

Comment: You example data consists of strings, in your text you write that you have datetime objects. You should maybe clarify that, some of the solutions are specific for strings, you'll have to slightly rewrite them for datetime objects.

Comment: @Fabian: I was aware of that 'conflict', when composing the question - but I wasn't quite sure how to represent datetime objects in text. Is there a convention used by Python programmers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [min(j) for i, j in itertools.groupby(A, key=lambda x: x[:7])]
['2001/01/01', '2001/02/04', '2001/03/01', '2001/04/10', '2001/05/07', '2001/07/01', '2002/03/01', '2002/04/01']
```

Comment: nice! - BUT, I don't understand it. Care to explain whats going on, so us mere mortals can understand ;) ?

Comment: Check out the itertools.groupby() documentation (http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). And make sure the list is sorted if you use this solution, else it won't work.

Comment: @morpheous: I group dates based on month (first 7 character of day string), then select minimum value from the group, which forms an element of the output list.

Comment: @Fabian: list `A` needs to be sorted by months, e.g. `['2001/01/03','2001/01/01','2001/01/05']` would still produce `['2001/01/01']`

Comment: I simplified my statement a bit too much, the list only needs to be sorted with the same key function (or generated in an equivalent manner).

Answer (score 1):

Searching lists is a O(*n*) operation. I think you can simply check whether the key is new:

```
def extract_month_first_dates(input_list):
    output = []
    last_key = None
    for curr_date in input_list:
        date_key = curr_date.date.month, curr_date.date.year  # no string key required
        if date_key != last_key:
            output.append(curr_date)
            last_key = date_key
    return output
```

Comment: @phillip: +1 for the useful tip!. BTW, you are assigning to variables to one - whats going on?. Is the comma operator overloaded for integers in Python?

Comment: @morpheous: Comma is a standard operator in Python. The value of the expression `x, y` is a tuple consisting of `x` and `y`. In your original example, `[], []` is also just a tuple consisting of two empty lists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution in `classic python` i.e. no itertools ;) and self explanatory

```
visited = {}
B = []
for a in A:
    month = a[:7]
    if month not in visited:
        B.append(a)
    visited[month] = 1

print B
```

Ouput:

```
['2001/01/01', '2001/02/04', '2001/03/01', '2001/04/10', '2001/05/07', '2001/07/01', '2002/03/01', '2002/04/01']
```